# Can't pass JSON array with AJAX

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get a PHP array with AJAX and turn it into a JSON array.

Right now in the external file I'm echoing the php array with JSON encoding:

```
echo json_encode($palabras);
```

Then on the main file I get the response and assign it to variable "jsarray ";

```
success:function(data_response){
    jsarray = data_response;
    }});
```

However I can't access `jsarray` as an array. How can I turn it into a proper array I can access?

Comment: Are you *requesting* a JSON response?

Comment: what is the value of data_response ??

Comment: Add `console.log(jsarray)` in the `success` function and have a look. If nothing is logged then `sucess` was not called -> error occured. In that case edit your question and add exact output from your php page echoing JSON and also client-side code that is using AJAX.

Comment: the PHP is echoing: `[{"palabra":"uno"},{"palabra":"dos"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 100% certain you can trust the contents of `data_response`, you can simply evaluate it.

I don't know what library you are using, but that should be something like `jsarray = eval(data_response.responseText);`

**WARNING**: This does pose a security risk if a third party can inject data into `data_response`. Since it's a simple `eval()`, any javascript code can be executed.

I believe that most modern webbrowsers provide a JSON library to work around this issue. You should be able to use `JSON.parse(data_response.responseText)` in that case. However, that will not work on all browsers.

Comment: I think that might fix my problem, but I couldn't implement it. `alert(data_response)` produces: `[{"palabra":"aa"}]`. If I use eval or JSON.parse I get: `[object Object]`. But I can't manage to access the object. How can I make get the value on key 1 or "palabra" for example? thanks

Comment: That looks like an array of objects. If you want to get the first object's value for `palabra`, you'll want `jsarray[0]['palabra']`. If you want all `palabra` values in your arrays, you'll want to iterate: `for (var i = 0; i < jsarray.length; i++) { var item = jsarray[i]; alert(item['palabra']); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval:

```
eval(data_response)
```

You can use [jquery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) too:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data_response);
```

Comment: -1 for immediately suggesting heavy libraries such as jQuery.

Comment: @Tom what's wrong with mentioning jQuery as an additional solution? +1 to even out.